# Visual studio build tools 2019 installation error

Tags: visual-studio

I got this error when i tried to install visual studio build tools 2019 in windows 10 using latest visual studio installer.

An installation file didn't download

After nine attempts, there was a problem downloading the following file: https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/5eeaf3c7-015f-442c-8d63-aea17e5e6aef/6ec381fa716a2ed419c2141cc09606ee/a1e2a83aa8a71c48c742eeaff6e71928.cab

Select Continue to install Visual Studio without downloading this file. This might cause problems with other parts of the installation.

Select Retry to try downloading the file again.

Select Cancel to cancel the Visual Studio install.

Get help installing behind a firewall or proxy server.

Continue

Retry

Cancel

[image: stuck at 97% :(]

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, tried restating the pc, tried the retry button on the error. Nothing works.. when i copy the link and paste it in a browser, a file downloads.

help me solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZKUCejkRc0s

this video helped me

1. Run your Services.msc as administrator
2. Locate the "CNG Key Isolation" service and open it
3. Change the "Startup type" option to "Manual" and start it
4. Download the Visual Studio and try again(in my case  just clicked on retry)